# Static and local variable connection in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, static

I am confused and need some help about connection between static and local variable in flutter, please see my code attachment below,

```
void main() {
  var tempData = A.getData();
  var tmpMyInt = A.myInt;
  
  print("tmpMyInt Before: ${tmpMyInt.toString()}");
  print('tempData Before: ${tempData}');
  
  A.data[0]= "1 piggy";
  A.data[1]= "2 piggy";  
  A.myInt = 150;
  
  print('tempData after : ${tempData}');
  print("tmpMyInt after: ${tmpMyInt.toString()}");
}

class A {
  static List<dynamic> data = [
    "1","2"
  ];
  
  static int myInt = 10;

  static getData() {
    return data;
  }

  static setData(int idx, var value) {
    data[idx]= value;
  }
}
```

and for the debug output is:

```
tmpMyInt Before: 10
tempData Before: [1, 2]
tempData after : [1 piggy, 2 piggy]
tmpMyInt after: 10
```

I wonder why `tempData` value changed or is different between before and after and the same does not happen for `tmpMyInt` value?

As you can see in my code, I just change the static variable value (`data` and `myInt`) and never updated the new static variable value into `tempData` and `tmpMyInt` as a local variable in the main function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I want to point out that this is a question about Dart programming language.

- When you assign a complex object (like a List or Map) to a variable, you are actually assigning a reference to that object. This means that if you modify the object, the changes will be visible through any reference to that object.
- For primitive types (like int, double, bool), when you assign a variable, you are making a copy of that value. So, changes to the original variable won’t affect the copied value.

The difference in behavior between `tempData` and `tmpMyInt` is due to the fact that `tempData` is a reference to a mutable list object, while `tmpMyInt` is of type `int`.

So `A.data` and `tempData` point to the same object and any modifications made via `A.data` are reflected when you print the value obtained from `tempData`. But in case of `tmpMyInt` and `A.myInt`, updates to `A.myInt` are not reflected in `tmpMyInt`.

You can read the following resource for more in-depth explanation (this concept is similar across numerous programming languages):

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primitive-data-type-vs-object-data-type-in-java-with-examples/#

Comment: is it vice versa connection? if we change local variable it can be have affect for the "complex object" which it have been assigned?

Comment: Yes. You could do `tempData[0] = "1 piggy";` and then observe the changes via `print('A.data after : ${A.data}');`